# Grouping messages as conversations

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by

I'm trying to group messages in conversations, so they can be read as a conversation.

### This is what I have right now

**Table `messages`**

```
id | from | to | message | timestamp  
1  | 1    | 2  | 'Hello' | 1351257766
2  | 1    | 3  | 'Hey!'  | 1351257767
3  | 2    | 1  | 'Hay!'  | 1351257768
```

Whereas the `messages.from` and `messages.to` fields  correspond to a row in the `users` table.

**What I want to do is: (not in the same query)**

a. Get a list of the last messages of all the conversations from a user (so where either `from` or `to` is equal to a given `user.id`
b. Get all the messages that belong to a conversation.

```
SELECT
-- From-user:
    users_from.id               AS from_id,
    users_from.username         AS from_username,
    users_from.nickname         AS from_nickname,
    users_from.username_safe    AS from_username_safe,
    users_from.password         AS from_password,
    users_from.email            AS from_email,
    users_from.rank             AS from_rank,
    users_from.email            AS from_email,
    users_from.ip               AS from_ip,
    users_from.last_online      AS from_last_online,
    users_from.register_stamp   AS from_register_stamp,
    users_from.state            AS from_state,
    users_from.icon             AS from_icon,

-- To-user:
    users_to.id                 AS to_id,
    users_to.username           AS to_username,
    users_to.nickname           AS to_nickname,
    users_to.username_safe      AS to_username_safe,
    users_to.password           AS to_password,
    users_to.email              AS to_email,
    users_to.rank               AS to_rank,
    users_to.email              AS to_email,
    users_to.ip                 AS to_ip,
    users_to.last_online        AS to_last_online,
    users_to.register_stamp     AS to_register_stamp,
    users_to.state              AS to_state,
    users_to.icon               AS to_icon,

-- Messages:
    messages.id,
    messages.from,
    messages.to,
    messages.message,
    messages.timestamp


FROM messages

-- Some joins to get the userdata
INNER JOIN users AS users_to
    ON messages.to = users_to.id
INNER JOIN users AS users_from
    ON messages.from = users_from.id

-- We only want the latest messages:
RIGHT JOIN (
    SELECT
        max(messages.id) AS maxid,
        messages.from,
        messages.to
    FROM messages
    WHERE messages.to = {userid} OR messages.from = {userid}
) limiter
    ON messages.id = limiter.maxid
```

This is what I am using right now, but it isn't working. It returns only one of the conversations.

I hope you guys can help me make this work!

**UPDATE:**
The answer that was given did not work. When user-1 sent a message to user-2, it worked. However when user-2 replied, it began a separate conversation (as a new row in the result).

Comment: I don't think you can do it with the data you have.  I see nothing that identifies a conversation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is close, but I think you need to group by the users as well.  This is one approach

```
RIGHT JOIN (
    SELECT
        max(messages.id) AS maxid,
        messages.from,
        messages.to
    FROM messages
    WHERE messages.to = {userid} OR messages.from = {userid}
    group by messages.from, messages.to
) limiter
```

Your definition of conversation appears to be having the same two users.  For this, use `in`:

```
select m.*
from messages m
where `from` in ({userid1}, {userid2}) and
      `to` in ({userid1}, {userid2})
```

By the way, `from` and `to` are bad column names, because `from` is a reserved word.

Comment: Thanks! This is actually working right now. I will go and test it a bit more extensively.

Comment: How would you suggest I get a query for the b-part of my question?

Comment: I'm sorry but this didn't work. When user '1' sends a message to '2', it's okay. But when '2' replies, they are seen as 2 seperate entries. I want 2 -> 1 and 1 -> 2 as one conversation.

Comment: @jeroenvisser101 . . . You would need to clarify what you mean by that.  The second query gets all the messages between two people.  That seems to be the definition of conversation that you are using.

Comment: I've found a better, easier solution for this. I have a new table that holds a record of every conversation. This way, there are no extreme queries ;) Thanks though!